Multiple selection dropdown list not working on a protected sheet
I want to relocate the code line responsible for unprotecting sheet with password, so if only i choose the multiple selection dropdown lists, the code unprotects the sheet to allow the multiple selection in the designated cells, then reprotecting the sheet again if i transfered to any other cell, Knowing that i allowed some unproteced cells in the sheet.
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Destination As Range)
Dim rngDropdown As Range
Dim oldValue As String
Dim newValue As String
Dim DelimiterType As String
DelimiterType = ", "
Dim DelimiterCount As Integer
Dim TargetType As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim arr() As String
 
If Destination.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next

Set rngDropdown = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitError
 
If rngDropdown Is Nothing Then GoTo exitError
If Destination.Column <> 16 And Destination.Column <> 17 And Destination.Column <> 18 And Destination.Column <> 19 And Destination.Column <> 20 And Destination.Column <> 21 And Destination.Column <> 22 And Destination.Column <> 23 And Destination.Column <> 24 And Destination.Column <> 29 Then GoTo exitError
TargetType = 0
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Password"
    TargetType = Destination.Validation.Type
    If TargetType = 3 Then  ' is validation type is "list"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        newValue = Destination.Value
        Application.Undo
        oldValue = Destination.Value
        Destination.Value = newValue
        If oldValue <> "" Then
            If newValue <> "" Then
                If oldValue = newValue Or oldValue = newValue & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "") Or oldValue = newValue & DelimiterType Then ' leave the value if there is only one in the list
                    oldValue = Replace(oldValue, DelimiterType, "")
                    oldValue = Replace(oldValue, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), "")
                    Destination.Value = oldValue
                ElseIf InStr(1, oldValue, DelimiterType & newValue) Or InStr(1, oldValue, newValue & DelimiterType) Or InStr(1, oldValue, DelimiterType & newValue & DelimiterType) Then
                    arr = Split(oldValue, DelimiterType)
                If Not IsError(Application.Match(newValue, arr, 0)) = 0 Then
                    Destination.Value = oldValue & DelimiterType & newValue
                        Else:
                    Destination.Value = ""
                    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
                    If arr(i) <> newValue Then
                        Destination.Value = Destination.Value & arr(i) & DelimiterType
                    End If
                    Next i
                Destination.Value = Left(Destination.Value, Len(Destination.Value) - Len(DelimiterType))
                End If
                ElseIf InStr(1, oldValue, newValue & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) Then
                    oldValue = Replace(oldValue, newValue, "")
                    Destination.Value = oldValue
                Else
                    Destination.Value = oldValue & DelimiterType & newValue
                End If
                Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "") & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) ' remove extra commas and spaces
                Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, DelimiterType & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""))
                If Destination.Value <> "" Then
                    If Right(Destination.Value, 2) = DelimiterType Then  ' remove delimiter at the end
                        Destination.Value = Left(Destination.Value, Len(Destination.Value) - 2)
                    End If
                End If
                If InStr(1, Destination.Value, DelimiterType) = 1 Then ' remove delimiter as first characters
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, DelimiterType, "", 1, 1)
                End If
                If InStr(1, Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) = 1 Then
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), "", 1, 1)
                End If
                DelimiterCount = 0
                For i = 1 To Len(Destination.Value)
                    If InStr(i, Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) Then
                        DelimiterCount = DelimiterCount + 1
                    End If
                Next i
                If DelimiterCount = 1 Then ' remove delimiter if last character
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, DelimiterType, "")
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), "")
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If

ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Password"
exitError:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
 
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 
End Sub


Please help me on that as i tried many options and made a lot of searches without any results.

What exactly is the problem you're having with your code?

I have an Excel sheet table with columns from A to AF
Columns P to X and Column AC are multi-selection columns (Using the attached VBA code).
I chose to lock editing columns A and H as they contain Serials and Equation and allowed other cells for editing - I unlocked all columns except A and H through the format cell - Protection - Then removed the tick mark beside the Lock option, and protected the sheet with password and allowed the users to choose unlocked cell.
After locking the sheet, the multi-selection cells (P to X and AC) lost the multi-selection option (See next comment)

After searching i discovered that I need to add two codes in the above VBA code, the first line to unprotect the sheet to allow the multi-select option, and the second line is to reprotect the sheet.
When I used the above VBA code, the multi-selection option didn't work, I think my problem is where to put this line (ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Password") in the code, as when I put the unprotect line at the beginning of the VBA code, I lost the protection of the sheet leading to columns A and H to be modified which is not required (See next comment)

So, I want the sheet to be protected until click the multi-selection cells, when choosing multi selection cell, I need the sheet to be unprotected to allow the multi-selection option and when to move to another cell that is not a multi-selection cell, the sheet becomes reprotected again to prevent users from modifying the lock cells (A and H).

Typically if there are ranges you want users to be able to edit, you'd unlock the cells in those ranges before protecting the sheet.  That's easier than doing essentially the same thing on the fly via code.

Dear Tim Williams, that's already what I did, the problem is not how to protect the sheet, the problem is the VBA code that I use for activating the multiple selection columns features is not working on the protected sheet, so you need to insert a line code in the VBA to activate the sheet if you select a multiple selection column/cell then another code to reprotect the sheet again after finishing dealing with a multiple selection column/cell.

I inserted the two lines of codes responsible for unprotecting and reprotecting the sheet but the VBA multiple selection was disabled, so it seems that I put them in the wrong location or the whole code needs a little modification.
The code responsible for activating the sheet to activate the multi-selection VBA (ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Password")
The code responsible for re-protecting the sheet after moving from a multi-selection cell to a single-selection cell. (ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Password")
